# Where is "startup applications" user config file for disabled and enabled applications?

Tags: configuration, startup, backup

It is the `gnome-session-properties` command.

I know already the apps are at `~/.config/autostart`.

I know there are files at `/etc` but those are root.

I found nothing at `gconf-editor`.

I need to know where `gnome-session-properties` stores what apps are disabled and enabled to auto startup, so I can backup that file.

Comment: /home/User_Name/.config/gnome-session/saved-session & /home/User_Name/.config/autostart are the two locations they are stored I don't know if the first one is the one you are looking for or not.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63407/where-are-startup-commands-stored

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you edit the files inside `~/.config/autostart/` they are written in this way:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

The last line is the one that specifies if the app is enabled or not (check it by yourself with the `gnome-session-properties` enabling and disabling an app and noticing the change of that option in the file).

Then, you only have to copy all the files inside the folder to make a backup of that configuration.

Comment: By opening gedit with sudo, I have just found this one as well.

Comment: oh! some files dont have that!! so I miss-guessed it would be elsewhere.. thx!

Answer (score 1):

It does not store the data in a single file. The autostart files are copied into `~/.config/autostart` when you configure them, and they are modified in there. So you should simply back up that directory if you wish to save that configuration.