# Run BleachBit CLI at startup

Tags: autostart, bleachbit

In BleachBit, if I go to *Edit > Preferences > General*, I can check the *"Start BleachBit with computer"* checkbox, but this will only launch the BleachBit GUI every time I start my computer, without actually cleaning.

[image: BleachBit Preferences]

Instead, I would prefer to run the BleachBit CLI silently in the background and do the cleaning automatically using my presets, using the following command:

```
bleachbit -c --preset
```

I have tried setting up a `cron` job with the `@reboot` option. I also tried adding an entry in `/etc/rc.local` but neither method worked.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> This answer has been adapted from [Takkat's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/643185) answering the
>   question [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/643185)

### Option 1: Editing the desktop configuration file manually

When the *"Start BleachBit with computer"* checkbox is activated, it creates a desktop configuration file called `bleachbit` in `~/.config/autostart/`. This is very well explained in the posts [Where are startup commands stored?](https://askubuntu.com/q/63407/643185) and [where is “startup applications” user config file for disabled and enabled applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/303694/643185)

[image: desktop configuration file in autostart]

If you want to access the folder with `nautilus` make sure to enable *View > Show Hidden Files*, or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut.

Edit the file with your text editor of choice, for example using `gedit`. Open the terminal and run the command:

```
gedit ~/.config/autostart/bleachbit
```

Inside the file, locate the line `Exec=bleachbit` and replace it with:

```
Exec=bleachbit -c --preset
```

Save the changes. We're done.

Notice that after saving, the desktop configuration file is renamed automatically to `bleachbit.desktop`. This is default behavior.

[image: renamed desktop configuration file in autostart]

---

### Option 2: Using the `gnome-session-properties` interface

If you prefer not to mess around with the desktop configuration file, you can use the [`gnome-session-properties`](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) interface, which will do that for you.

First, open BleachBit and make sure that the *"Start BleachBit with computer"* checkbox is activated.

Next, open the terminal and run:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

The `man` page reads:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `gnome-session-properties` program enables the users to configure
>   what applications should be started on login, in addition to the
>   default startup applications configured on the system.
>
> It also proposes an interface to save a snapshot of the currently
>   running applications so that they can automatically be restored to
>   their current state on your next GNOME session.

It will open the Startup Applications Preferences panel:

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Select the *"BleachBit"* entry and click on *"Edit"*.

Locate the *"Command"* field and replace the string with `bleachbit -c --preset`

[image: Edit Startup Program]

[image: Edit Startup Program]

Click on *"Save"*. We're done.

Answer (score 0):

What line did you use to set up the cron job? I have a few set up to run on boot on my server and they work perfectly.

In my own crontab file (in `/var/spool/crontabs`) this is one of the working entries

```
@reboot /home/will/scripts/bootup.sh   #notify of boot
```

I set this up through webmin but I'd guess it's the context that matters and not how it got there.

have you tried the command with the full bleachbit path?

I like to set up a dedicated script to run as a cron job or any other automated startup that isn't set up by the system itself, then I can test the script to make sure my command is correct and works, it makes it easier to troubleshoot issues I think.