# Xubuntu - Apps loading at start up

Tags: xubuntu

Every time I log into Xubuntu, apps like Libre Office and the web browser keep opening. How can I stop this?

The apps that show up are:

- Firefox
- Geary
- Hotot
- Bunch of error messages
- Keyring password permission

Comment: I can imagine 2 kinds of problem: 1) Old Session restored: Did you have the have the programs open the last time you logout / shutdown? Then the applications should change. 2) Autostart: Do the same apps open every time? Then we have to configue autstart.

Answer (score 8):

Check in Settings Manager - Session and Startup.

That Automatically save session is not enabled

[image]

Then in Application Autostart you do not have an entry for the Applications you find starting.

[image]

Then you can clear any saved sessions from the Session Tab

[image]

Comment: any idea what files these settings are stored in?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/63413