# Loading Session Applications

Tags: boot, kernel, system, programming, startup-applications

How does Ubuntu Load previously opened applications on startup? (I want to code and modify that functionality present in the system preferences manually )

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't "load previously opened applications on start-up" out-of-the-box.

Try this: open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> log off and log on again: the terminal doesn't open automatically and if it does on your system, you have an application installed that does that for you. (but I wouldn't know which: check your system settings.

If your question is "How should I add applications to the autostart", then please edit your question to make this clearer and then you have two possibilities:

**Using the GUI**

Go to the dash, type `Startup Applications` and any application you want opened at login.

**Using the command line**

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63407/where-are-startup-commands-stored) for the file locations of these commands.  You can then add those programmatically.