# How to disable onedrive service from autostarting

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, systemd, services, autostart

I installed "onedrive" from repo.
Works great but I don't want it to start automatically.
I'm tired of turning it off after each reboot - how to fix it?
I'm turning it off using `systemctl --user stop onedrive`
I was expecting `systemctl --user disable onedrive` will turn off autostart but it has no effect - `systemctl --user status onedrive` stil shows `enabled;`:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/onedrive.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

and it starts after reboot.

Comment: Quite some explanation here. May depend on the configuration. https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#running-onedrive-as-a-system-service

Comment: FYI - this issue is a Ubuntu PPA Packaging Bug as detailed here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/1274

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This issue is caused by the Ubuntu PPA package creating a symbolic link when the package is installed:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/onedrive.service → /usr/lib/systemd/user/onedrive.service.
```

To resolve this situation, this symbolic link needs to be removed:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/onedrive.service
```

To fix this issue permanently, the PPA package needs to be updated so that this symbolic link is not created.

The above information is also listed in https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/1274 which tracks this particular issue.

Comment: Can confirm:I had this same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.3 with onedrive v2.4.25-1+np1
and these steps successfully stopped it from starting automatically

Answer (score 0):

If the app is located in `startup applications` it is accessed by pressing left windows (or whatever you have set up as your <kbd>Super</kbd> key) and typing `startup` in the search box, select the `startup applications` icon then disable `OneDrive` from there by highlighting it and then clicking on `remove`.

Just to be clear, this will only remove `OneDrive` from Startup Applications - it will not remove it from your system.

[image]

Comment: Using kubuntu... but no, no mention of onedrive in startup applications. I also had "Stacer" installed so I checked there but no mentions of onedrive either in the startup apps or services.

Comment: Not a kubuntu user but does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/63413/307670) help in any way?